# Exporting functions with C type as a parameter [cannot use x (type *C.ctype) as type *package.C.ctype in argument to package.Func]

Tags: go, cgo

#### Library Code (Simplified Version):

```golang
// package1.go

package package1

import "C"

func Play(s *C.char) {
}
```

#### Client Code:

```golang
// main.go

package main

import "C"

import (
    "path/to/package1"
)

func PlayMore(s *C.char) {
    package1.Play(s)
}

func main() {
}
```

#### Build Error:

```
# command-line-arguments
main.go:12: cannot use s (type *C.char) as type *package1.C.char
            in argument to package1.Play
```

It seems that the "C" package is local to each package, the compiler treats them as different packages. I tried something like:

```golang
func PlayMore(s *package1.C.char) {
    package1.Play(s)
}
```

But then it is a syntax error.

#### Question:

- How can I make the code compile?

#### More Information:

In the original problem, the parameter type is not `*C.char`. It is a pointer to a C type from a legacy library.

`package1` has a low-level API and a high-level API:

- The low-level API just wraps the C signatures with Go syntax. The parameter and return types are `C.xxx` types.
- The high-level API provides a pure Go interface to the legacy library, which means there are no `C.xxx` parameter or return types. For instance, `string` is used instead of `*C.char`. The implementation prepares the parameters, and calls the low-level API for actual work.

The client code above (the `main` package), is in fact another package (`package2`) which is intended to be callable from C. You can treat it as a C library built on top of another C library, but the implementation is written in Go. For instance, `PlayMore()` above is exported in the original problem, via `//export PlayMore`, in order to be callable from C.

When `package2` needs to call the functions provided by the legacy library, it calls the low-level API of `package1`. In fact, the reason why the low-level API of `package1` is public is to allow packages like `package2` to reuse it.

#### Related Questions:

[Trouble using exported function type with C types as parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31099620/142239)

[Go: Exporting functions with anonymous struct as a parameter [cannot use value (type struct {...}) as type struct {...} in argument to package.Func]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38784963/142239)

Answer (score 1):

You may Export: `type ExportedType C.char`,like this working sample code:

```golang
package package1

import "C"
import "fmt"

type ExportedType C.char

func Play(s *ExportedType) {
    fmt.Println(C.GoString((*C.char)(s)))
}
```

main code:

```golang
package main

import "C"

import (
    "path/to/package1"
)

func PlayMore(s *C.char) {
    package1.Play((*package1.ExportedType)(s))
}

func main() {
    PlayMore(C.CString("Hi"))
}
```

output:

```
Hi
```

Comment: Thanks! But this doesn't seem to work if `C.char` is replaced by a pointer type. In the original problem, `C.char` above is in fact a pointer to an opaque type.

Comment: @siu-ching-pong-asuka-kenji  Yes, use exactly in this style. this is tested and works fine.

Comment: What I mean is the code above is a simplified version of the actual code. In the original problem, it is not a `const char*` on the C side. It is a "pointer to pointer to an opaque type". By opaque type, it means the `struct` is declared but not defined, like this: `struct _otype; typedef struct _otype* otype; void play(otype* x);`. So, `x` is effectively "pointer to pointer to struct _otype`. In the original problem, function pointers are involved too, so things get some how complicated. It doesn't seem to work right now, but let me tweak it a little bit to see if it does.

Comment: Use `type ExportedType C.otype` like:  `package package1

/*
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct _otype{
 int8_t buf[16];
}otype;
otype o = {0};
otype *p = &o;
otype **q = &p;
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

type ExportedType C.otype

func Play(s **ExportedType) {
 fmt.Println("Hi")
}` and `func main() {
 var t *package1.ExportedType
 p := &t
 package1.Play(p)
}`

Comment: `otype` is declared by the legacy library, not by the Go wrapper I'm writing, so I have no control over it. The type is opaque, which means that the header from the legacy library doesn't define the size and layout of the `struct` --- thus it is not always 16 bytes. Using opaque types is the C way to make it "platform independent". The details of the `struct` is vendor specific.

Comment: I tried applying your solution to my project. It doesn't work. I found that only types as simple as `char` works. More complicated types don't work. The compiler complains that in `(*package1.ExportedType)(s)`, the conversion is not possible.

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji-  So you may Ask new question about your original problem with more details.

Comment: In the original problem, the legacy library is a big one (Java Native Interface, aka JNI, to be exact). Most of the types, such as `jobject`, `jfieldID` and `jmethodID` are pointers to opaque types. Other types like `JNIEnv` and `JavaVM` contains function pointers, which I need to write a C wrapper first in order to call them. In the low level library, I wrote helper functions to convert C types and release them. The original code is available here: https://github.com/asukakenji/go/blob/master/jni/typeconv.go#L147-L151 Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The low-level API code is available here: https://github.com/asukakenji/go/blob/master/jni/jnienv_low_level.go You can see that I need a C wrapper (the static functions) in order to invoke the function pointers contained in the `JNIEnv` struct. At https://github.com/asukakenji/go/blob/master/jni/typeconv.go#L147-L151 , the client needs to provide "a function accepting a `*C.char`". But since the `*C.char` type is not "cross-package", I may need to write it as `func WithCString(s string, f func(*ExportedType))`, which is not good looking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Go don't support export C type across packages. Related issue:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13467

A workaround is to pass unsafe.Pointer, and do a type cast inside this method.

- https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13467#issuecomment-228850970